# How to replicate Win+UP to maximize undecorated windows?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, fxml

i'm trying to replicate decorate Window behavior on an undecorated window, i wanna use Win+UP keys combination to maximize my window but i can't manage to put KeyCode.WINDOWS in the KeyCodeCombination so i've used CONTROL_ANY to test it and it works but i'd prefer to use Windows key instead of Ctrl, can someone help me?
Here's the code i've managed to write:

```
public final KeyCombination keyMax = new KeyCodeCombination
            (KeyCode.UP, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);

@FXML
private void onKeyMaximize(KeyEvent event){
 Stage stage = (Stage) pane1.getScene().getWindow();
   if(keyMax.match(event)){
     if(stage.isMaximized()){
       }else {
         stage.setMaximized(true);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Add an event *filter* for all key events sent to the window.  Don’t use fxml just [directly set it on the stage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#addEventFilter(javafx.event.EventType,javafx.event.EventHandler)).  Test it for standard alphanumeric keys as well as control, shift, esc, etc, to make sure it is logging as expected.  Then test for the windows key and various windows key combinations.  If the events involving the windows key are logged, you can add appropriate conditions to filter only them, otherwise you can’t.

Comment: If you can’t do this with in-built JavaFX key handling, you could perhaps get it working with [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook). Integrating that nativehook library into JavaFX apps is a little tricky due to modularity and the native portions of the library, especially if you want to package using jlink or jpackage.